# Unix grep line above and concatenate

Tags: unix, grep

here is my sample input from a log file.

```
#2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1300#
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[UserID= testUser]
```

What I am trying to do is go through all the log entries and do a grep command on the "UserID=" and then get the line 2 lines above (the timestamp). I then wish my output file to be a concatenation of the two into the file tempLog.txt

```
 #2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1300# [UserID= testUser]
```

Can anyone help me with this? Still kinda new to Unix.... :)

Thanks
Chris

UPDATED DUMMY DATA

```
#2.#2014 03 06 11:21:29:163#+1300#Info#/System/Security/Audit/Logon#
#xxxxxx (Has white spaces)
Logon failed    | LOGIN.ERROR   | null  |       | Login Method=[default], IP Address=[xx.xx.xxxx], UserID=[testUser], Reason=[Authentication did not succeed.]#
```

Comment: use `man grep` and see if your `grep` has the `-C, -B, -A` options. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. It does have the options but using -B includes the unwanted line of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this line a try:

```
grep --group-separator="" -B2 'UserID=' file|awk -v RS="" -F '\n' '{$2=""}7'
```

test:

```
 kent$  cat f
fooba
#2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1300#
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[UserID= testUser]
foo

bar
#2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1400#
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[UserID= testUser2]

kent$  grep --group-separator="" -B2 'UserID=' f|awk -v RS="" -F '\n' '{$2=""}7'
#2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1300#  [UserID= testUser]
#2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1400#  [UserID= testUser2]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Can you walk me through the logic though? I am following up to the pipe but I don't understand what you are doing with the awk. (Unfortunately it is not working correctly. Most likely due to me oversimplifying the dummy data)

Comment: @Chris after grep, we have `3 lines, empty line, 3lines...` structure. the awk uses the `empty line` as record sep, and new line (`\n`) as Field sep, so the `xxxx` would the 2nd field. I set it to empty because you don't want it to be in your output. `OFS` was not set, so it is default: whitespace.  so we have the output. If you don't understand what is RS what is FS or OFS, you have to read `man awk or man gawk` to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Kent. Will play with it further to tweak it to my input. Your code works great on my initial dummy data so will mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/#20/ {f=$0} /\[UserID/ {print f,$0}' file
#2014 03 06 11:21:44:028#+1300# [UserID= testUser]
```